# Laravel. Disable system migration create_password_reset_tokens_table

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I have a Laravel project. I already have a database with system tables: users, migrations, jobs, etc. However, when I try to run the command

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get an error

```
create_password_reset_tokens_table - FAIL
```

I don't want to do this migration. How can I skip it or turn it off in Laravel configuration files? Is far as I understand, it comes with the Laravel/UI package and therefore it makes no sense to remove it from the vendor because the composer will download it anyway.